# set UIViewController delegate from appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, appdelegate

I am trying to set the delegate of a view controller from my app delegate.
But it does not work.

*AppDelegate.m:*

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                              bundle:nil];

SFLoginViewController * LoginVC = (SFLoginViewController *)[sb
                                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
LoginVC.delegate = self;
```

*SFLoginViewController.m*

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate); //returns nil (!!)

  //It should call the delegate method here
  [[self delegate] LoginSucceeded];

}
```

any help?

Comment: Do you add LoginVC to the view hierarch in AppDelegate after you add self as a delegate? Where do you call NSLog in SFLoginVC.m?

Comment: @Greg what do you mean by view hierach? I call it within a UIbutton touch event (that triggers the login procedure)..

Comment: Maybe if you post more of the  relevant code

Comment: I think, that the NSLog statement, is being executed before the loginVC.delegate = self; statement, thus - the SFLoginViewController object is created and fires the NSLog message, BEFORE you set the delegate. where in the SFLoginViewController is the NSlog statement?

Comment: What happens if you move the NSLog Statement to the appdelegate.... What is the output of....    NSLog(@"%@", loginVC.delegate); AND   NSLog(@"%@",loginVC);  ... if you put these two statements after you set the delegate in the AppDelegate??

Comment: By add to view hierarchy I mean do something like [self.view addSubview: LoginVC]; or presentViewController or push to navigation controller. When you don't add LoginVC to view hierarch it will be nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier%3a)...

> Discussion You use this method to create view controller objects that
>   you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your
>   application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view
>   controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier
>   string in Interface Builder.
>
> **This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller
>   each time you call it.**

I don't think the code you have in your appDelegate is returning the ViewController that is presented via the storyboard

Comment: Thanks! I was anticipating something like this. I will use @hw731 solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not set your delegate in the ViewController like this:

```
self.delegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then you'll be able to handle delegate events in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this

> (SFLoginViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];

you are creating a new instance of SFLoginViewController.

I assume that you already have an instance of this viewcontroller created from the storyboard.
The instance from the storyboad is the one who call its method login:(id)sender and not the one you assigned the delegate.

Try @hw731 answer or you need to add the delegate to the instance created from the storyboard (not to the one you'are creating in your appdelegate).